# Remove spaces & filename extension

Tags: string, bash

I need to process a large number of files through `pandoc` to convert them from various formats to markdown format. There's also an ancillary requirement to *"standardize"* the file names:

- all spaces are to be removed from the filename,
- the existing filename *extension* must be removed,
- the converted file must have the `.md` extension

I also need to do this in `bash`. I'm struggling with the first two... I can do them separately, but can't figure how to combine them. Assuming the current filename is `fileX`:

- this will remove spaces: `${fileX// /}`
- this will remove the filename extension: `${fileX%%.*}`

How do I combine these two operations to get a filename with no spaces, and no extension to use in my `pandoc` call:

```sh
pandoc "$fileX" -f docx -t gfm -s -o "$DESTINFOLDER/$(stdfilename).md"
```

where `stdfilename` has no spaces and no extension?

---

**FWIW:**

This is what I'm currently using. It works, but I want to do this without the `basename` utility. I'm not familiar with it & it may not exist on all systems.

```sh
pandoc "$file" -f docx -t gfm -s -o "$DESTINFOLDER/$(basename $(tr -d ' ' <<< "$file") .docx).md"
```

Comment: `tmp="${fileX// /}"; tmp="${tmp%.*}"` Now use `$tmp.md`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That's great, and it will work. But I've now realized I omitted something from my question. I wanted to combine these *filters* in such a way they could be used as the filename after the `-o` argument in `pandoc`. Sorry for that, I'm editing my question now.

Comment: That's a bit tricky because the *parameter expansions* (unlike *command* and *process* *substitutions*) only operate on parameters (variables). So for instance, you can't combine `"${${fileX// /}"%.*}.mx"` all in one because the outter `${....%.*}1 isn't operating on a parameter, it would be operating on a parameter expansion. Now, you could define a function does it all and outputs the final filename. If you could then executed the function `pandoc function` which could do it that way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `"$DESTINFOLDER/$(tmp="${fileX// /}"; tmp="${tmp%.*}" ; echo "$tmp").md"` should to work IMO

Comment: if you move `$(tmp="${fileX// /}"; tmp="${tmp%.*}" ; echo "$tmp.md"` into the function then I think you will have a better chance calling `"$DESTINFOLDER/$(funcname oldname)"` or something similar

Comment: Don’t worry about basename - it’s everywhere, as it’s been a regular part of Unix systems for years before Linux even started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best answer is the one I was already using. It requires the [`basename`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-basename-of-filename-or-directory-name/) utility, but apparently it's widely distributed.

```
pandoc "$file" -f docx -t gfm -s -o "$DESTINFOLDER/$(basename $(tr -d ' ' <<< "$file") .docx).md"
```